Insert MDTextField input from one screen into another KivyMD Label text field screen?
I need to take the MDTextField input from one KivyMD screen (EntryScreen) and insert it another KivyMD screen as the MDLabel text in another KivyMD screen (ConfirmationScreen). I have searched the internet for an answer and can't find it. How do I accomplish this? Here are the two KivyMD screen codes I have:
EntryScreen
<EntryScreen>
    name: 'entry_screen'
    MDCard:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 500, 750
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        elevation: 10
        padding: 25
        spacing: 25
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDLabel:
            id: number_label
            text: "3 Digit Number"
            font_size: 25
            halign: 'center'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            #padding_y: 15

        MDTextField:
            mode: "round"
            id: number
            input_filter: 'int'
            max_text_length: 3
            hint_text: "3 Digit Number"
            valign: 'center'
            icon_right: "apps"
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 250
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}

ConfirmationScreen
<ConfirmationScreen>
    name: 'confirm_screen'
    MDCard:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 500, 750
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        elevation: 10
        padding: 25
        spacing: 25
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDLabel:
            id: confirm_label
            text: input from EntryScreen
            font_size: 30
            halign: 'center'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            #padding_y: 15


Please provide a [mcve].

There are many different ways to achieve your goal.
One way would be to change the labels text before the Confirmation Screen is entered. This would be my solution (minimal code):
main.py
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp


class EntryScreen(MDScreen):
    num_field = ObjectProperty(None)
    
class ConfirmationScreen(MDScreen):
    def on_pre_enter(self):
        self.ids.confirm_label.text = self.manager.get_screen("entry_screen").num_field.text
    
    
class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("main.kv")

Test().run()

main.kv
<EntryScreen>
    name: 'entry_screen'
    num_field: num_field
    MDCard:
        MDLabel:
        MDTextField:
            id: num_field
            ...


<ConfirmationScreen>
    name: 'confirm_screen'
    MDCard:
        MDLabel:
            id: confirm_label
            ...



MDScreenManager:
    id: main_screen_manager
    EntryScreen:
    ConfirmationScreen:

I have added num_field as an ObjectProperty to the EntryScreen class to make the textfield accessible from the py file.
def on_pre_enter(self): #fires before a screen is entered
self.ids.confirm_label #gets you the label from the ConfirmationScreen.(could be replaced with another Objectproperty)
To get the Object Property from the other screen you need to get the screen manager. For example with self.manager if the screens are in the same manager.
With .get_screen(screen:str) you get the screen from which you can get the Object Property.
If you do not know what ObjectProperties are and how to work with them, I recommend you reading the documentation and the following question:
Property doc
Usage of ObjectProperty class
